# What does JavaLangAccess.blockedOn(Thread t, Interruptible b) do?

Tags: java, jvm, nio

From public javadoc:

> ```
> void blockedOn(Thread t, Interruptible b)
> ```
>
> Set thread's blocker field.

I did stack with that method during java nio researching, particulary AbstractInterruptibleChannel source code

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the OpenJDK it calls

```
/* The object in which this thread is blocked in an interruptible I/O
 * operation, if any.  The blocker's interrupt method should be invoked
 * after setting this thread's interrupt status.
 */
private volatile Interruptible blocker;
private Object blockerLock = new Object();

/* Set the blocker field; invoked via sun.misc.SharedSecrets from java.nio code
 */
void blockedOn(Interruptible b) {
synchronized (blockerLock) {
    blocker = b;
}
}
```

This is used to trigger an action when a thread is interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Seems, I did found answer in java.lang.Thread source code (Oracle/Sun JVM):

```
/* The object in which this thread is blocked in an interruptible I/O
 * operation, if any.  The blocker's interrupt method should be invoked
 * after setting this thread's interrupt status.
 */
private volatile Interruptible blocker;
private Object blockerLock = new Object();

/* Set the blocker field; invoked via sun.misc.SharedSecrets from java.nio code
 */
void blockedOn(Interruptible b) {
    synchronized (blockerLock) {
         blocker = b;
    }
}
public void interrupt() {
    if (this != Thread.currentThread())
        checkAccess();

    synchronized (blockerLock) {
        Interruptible b = blocker;
        if (b != null) {
        interrupt0();        // Just to set the interrupt flag
        b.interrupt();
        return;
        }
    }
    interrupt0();
}
```

So correct me if I wrong, my conclusions are:

- Interruptible is just callback for Thread interruption event
- Attach concrete interruptible instance to concrete class possible only with following code:   sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaLangAccess().blockedOn(threadInstance, intrInstance);